# Not validating html file tab characters

Tags: html, validation

Validation of this file gives some errors:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="loginForm2" action="#elegirCurso"><select name="flip-2" id="flip-2">
                <option value="off">No</option>
                <option value="on">Si</option>
            </select>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Errors:

```
Line 9, Column 16: Text not allowed in element select in this context.
                <option value="off">No</option>
Line 10, Column 16: Text not allowed in element select in this context.
                <option value="on">Si</option>
Line 11, Column 12: Text not allowed in element select in this context.
            </select>
```

I check with vi and I can see (option :set list) some charactes ^I (tab charactes):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>$
<html lang="en">$
<head>$
^I<meta charset="UTF-8">$
^I<title>Document</title>$
</head>$
<body>$
  <form id="loginForm2" action="#elegirCurso"><select name="flip-2" id="flip-2">$
^I     ^I<option value="off">No</option>$
^I        <option value="on">Si</option>$
^I    </select>$
    </form> $
</body>$
</html>$
```

If I delete them, it validate.
Any explanation? Tab is not allowed????

Comment: Which validation tool are you using?

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/, direct input